# Filter on the SalesOrder LineItems Committed Quantity

Tags: netsuite

I've created the saved search in which I'm getting both the sales order main line and line items columns in result.

I want to filter the sales order based on the line items committed quantity.

### Filter Needs to Apply,

If the SUM of all the line items committed quantity for any sales order is greater than zero then include it in the result.

In the below example the saved search filter needs to filter out the Sales Order 2.

Example:

Sales Order - 1: 
LineItem1 -> Committed Quantity - 1
LineItem2 -> Committed Quantity - 0

Sales Order - 2: 
LineItem1 -> Committed Quantity - 0
LineItem2 -> Committed Quantity - 0

Is this possible in Netsuite ?

Thanks,

Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible through saved search (you need to use summary criteria and summary fields). But, the results would be grouped by the SO internalid

In the standard criteria use "Type is Sales Order"
In the summary criteria use "Sum QuantityCommitted is greaterthan 0"

In the results,

1) add `Internalid` field with `Summary Type` as `Group`

2) add `Quantity Committed` field with `Summary Type` as `Sum`

The results will include only SO internal ids and quantity committed count. Including more fields in search may break the expected behaviour.

You could use `nlapiLoadSearch(null, SEARCH_ID).runSearch().getResults(0, 1000)` to get results and then iterate over results to get Ids and fire another search if you need other details in the search.